Drawing multicolumn table in latex in second row
I have the following problem with my table in Latex. I want the following structure but I didn't get the correct result.
I started to create the table like this but thats not how I want it.
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Multi-row table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\hline
\textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{test1} & \textbf{test2} & \textbf{test3} \\
\hline
\hline
    hello this is a test with tables in latex  & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & 5 & 5 & 5\\
    \hline
    num1 & num2 & num3 \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
    5 & 6 & 8 & 52 & 23 & 56 \\
    d & d & d & d  & d  & d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:structure}
\end{table}

That code creates this table.


(I've generalized the answer so that the table's target width can be smaller than \textwidth.)
Since it looks like you want the columns to all have the same width, I suggest you employ a tabularx environment. And, do use a \multicolumn{3}{...}{...} command to center the text string across the first three columns. Note that the code shown below allows automatic line breaking in the text string. I further suggest using the line-drawing macros of the booktabs package instead of \hline.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' col. type
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X' col. type
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{calc} % simplify calculation syntax
\newlength\tabwidth

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\centering

\caption{A table with many rows and columns}
\label{table:structure}

\setlength\tabwidth{\textwidth} % first, a full-width table
\begin{tabularx}{\tabwidth}{@{} *{6}{C} @{}}
\toprule
& & & \textbf{test1} & \textbf{test2} & \textbf{test3} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{%
    @{} >{\centering}p{\tabwidth/2-\tabcolsep}}{%
    hello this is a test with tables in latex} 
    & 5 & 5 & 5\\
    \midrule
    num1 & num2 & num3 & & \\
    \midrule
    1 & 2 & 3 &  8 &  9 & 10 \\
    5 & 6 & 8 & 52 & 23 & 56 \\
    d & d & d &  d &  d &  d \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{5mm}
\setlength\tabwidth{0.7\textwidth} % next, a reduced-width table
\begin{tabularx}{\tabwidth}{@{} *{6}{C} @{}}
\toprule
& & & \textbf{test1} & \textbf{test2} & \textbf{test3} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{%
    @{} >{\centering}p{\tabwidth/2-\tabcolsep}}{%
    hello this is a test with lots and lots of tables in \LaTeX} 
    & 5 & 5 & 5\\
    \midrule
    num1 & num2 & num3 & & \\
    \midrule
    1 & 2 & 3 &  8 &  9 & 10 \\
    5 & 6 & 8 & 52 & 23 & 56 \\
    d & d & d &  d &  d &  d \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}


That worked well thanks for your help!
